# How to download 2 files using Threadpool in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, file, xamarin, threadpool

I am using the below code to download PDF file in button click. How can we download 2 files in threadpool?

```
private async Task DownloadPDF(string urls, string shortName, object downloadProgressCalculator)
        {
            m_downLoadProgress = downloadProgressCalculator as DownloadProgressCalculator; 
            var pathFile = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            var absolutePath = pathFile.AbsolutePath;
            var m_documentMobiNames = shortName + ".pdf";
            var mobileFileNames = Path.Combine(absolutePath, m_documentMobiNames);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((object state) =>
            {
                try
                {

                    if (File.Exists(mobileFileNames))
                    {
                        File.Delete(mobileFileNames);
                    }
                    if (!File.Exists(mobileFileNames))
                    {
                        m_webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);

                        m_webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);
                        m_webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(urls), mobileFileNames);

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            });
        }
```

Please suggest your ideas on this.

Thanks

Comment: how to download 2 files using  m_webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(urls), mobileFileNames);

Comment: You want to download two files in the same time or in order? And two files are with the same file name? I saw your this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458602/how-to-download-2-files-in-xamarin-android), can't this answer solve your problem?